# jquery - find an attribute value?

Tags: jquery, find, each, children

I have a series of containers containing map data and links. Im using jquery to cycle through those containers to get certain data. In this situation im trying to get an attribute of a link.

I use the following jquery to get all of the html of each container.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".map_container").each(function () {
        alert($(this).find(".map_content").html());
    });
 });
```

This creates an alert with a few lines of html, the line im concerned with is below.

```
 <a class="map_link" value="67" location="home"> Visit home </a>
```

How could I alert value of the location attribute. So in this case "home".

Something like

```
$(this).find(".map_content").attr("location");
```

or if possible just find the location without having to find the map_content div first. so

```
$(this).find.attr("location");
```

or

```
$(this).find("a").attr("location");
```

what would be the correct way to get the location attribue of the map_link link?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find(".map_content").attr("location");
```

would be incorrect, since $('.map_content') would have no child with class `map_content`, hence you cannot find that.

Second option is wrong, since usage of `find` is wrong.

```
$(this).find("a").attr("location");
```

should be good.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/36/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".map_link").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("location"));
    });
 });
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/ydzb2/2/)